# Sum Offset from MS Excel to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

I've made an excel document from MS2013 (xlsx) that computes all numbers above it, because i want it to dynamically compute and adjust its own formula as i add more rows above it. But when i import this on google spreadsheets, the formula doesn't work anymore. here is the sample and formula

```
  A  B  C  D
1 3  3  2  2
2 4  3  4  5
3 5  6  4  3
4
5 12 12 10 10
```

the formula for A5 is **=SUM(A1:OFFSET(A5,-1,0))** 
when i add 1 more row above A5 the formula adjusts accordingly to the formula's current position. What's the correct formula for google spreadsheet?

Comment: found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962953/google-spreadsheet-sum-which-always-ends-on-the-cell-above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you this formula (it's certainly not the better solution, nevertheless it's a solution):

```
=sum(indirect("A1:"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to work if there are rows inserted above the range? With this formula it won't shift.  Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962953/google-spreadsheet-sum-which-always-ends-on-the-cell-above

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in your example:

```
=SUM(A1:A4)
```

If you start adding extra rows, then they will be automatically accounted for.