# Google Spreadsheet table with sums and easy row adding

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs

I simply can't find nothing on google,
I want to create a google spreadsheet table with sums and counts.

The sums and counts should be dynamic to the table rows.

It should be easy to add a row like in excel when you are on the last column, you click tab and another row is created.

Of course when another row is created, it is added to the ranges of the sums and counts

Comment: There is an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962953/google-spreadsheet-sum-which-always-ends-on-the-cell-above on how to make sums dynamic, but to the best of my knowledge there is no equivalent to using the tab in an Excel table and you can only insert a whole row in Google sheets.